# Not prime numbers contains only 2,3,5,7 optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, primes

Task is:

> You are given two positive integers a and b (b - a <= 20000). Complete
>   the function which returns a list of all those numbers in the interval
>   [a, b) whose digits are made up of prime numbers (2, 3, 5, 7) but
>   which are not primes themselves.
>
> Be careful about your timing!

My solution is:

```
def not_primes(a, b):
    def is_prime(n):
        if not n % 2 and n > 2:
            return False

        return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2))

    arr = [x for x in range(a, b) if all(i in {'2', '3', '5', '7'} for i in str(x))]
    return [x for x in arr if not is_prime(x)]
```

The idea was like to pre-sort values and verify is prime or not only for numbers composed by 2, 3, 5 or 7.

But for large ranges it's and lots of tests it's slow.

What could be the better way to improve performance?

Comment: what indentation are you talking about?

Comment: oops, yep, missed

Comment: You can find all primes in a particular range much faster [using a sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_primes#Prime_sieves)

Comment: Strange that a and b are <= 20000, when the highest number with such digits in that range is 7777.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not sure what is faster, the amount of numbers with those digits in a given range (btw you can exclude those finishing in 2 or 5) is much smaller than the range itself...

Comment: @jdehesa, actually the target is to find all non-primes numbers, so we should include those finishing in 2 or 5 in final result list, but skip the prime test for those numbers

Comment: @henrywongkk Sorry, you're right, thanks, I see I read that the other way around.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich it's about diff between a and b, that `b - a <= 20000`

Comment: Ahh, of course, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ArjunSingh suggested, start by creating an array which only has the digits {2,3,5,7}.  It also returns just the numbers in the range [a,b].

```
def interval(a, b):
    values = {0: [2,3,5,7]}
    magnitude = 1
    for r in range(1,10):
        magnitude *= 10
        values[r] = []
        for digit in values[0]:
            for value in values[r-1]:
                n = digit*magnitude + value
                if n <= b:
                    values[r].append(n)
                    continue
                return [v for r1 in range(1,r+1) for v in values[r1] if v >= a]
    return None    # b is outside of the range 10**10
```

Optimize the `is_prime` function to return False for numbers ending in 2 or 5.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 10 in [2,5]:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2))
```

Now we get the values in the interval, and only print those that are not prime numbers.

```
a = 220000
b = 240000
for i in interval(a,b):
    if not is_prime(i):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Suggestions for fast solution.

1. Generate a array `arr` where numbers have only these digits {2,3,5,7}
2. use pre-calculated array `is_prime` using sieve which will be more fast.
3. Generate a new array with only valid values in `arr` (which are not prime)
4. Use binary search in new array generated in 3rd step using a and b for count